# git bash terminal overwriting text while using mongoDB

Tags: git-bash

I am working with mongoDB through a git bash terminal but am unable to insert text between previously written text without overwriting it. This does not happen with the windows command line terminal nor in the VS code terminal. is there a setting that I am missing? This is really frustrating. I would prefer to use only git bash if possible, but this bug (if that's what it is) is kinda game breaking. Thanks in advance!